# Facing problems installing Apache Solr 4.x for Drupal 7 on a remote server

Tags: apache, solr, drupal-7, installation

I am trying to install Solr 4.6 with Drupal 7. For some reason, I am not able to. Probably, I am trying to install it on a remote server (my website server).

### Here are the steps I am doing:-

- Download Apache Solr Drupal Module from [here](https://drupal.org/project/apachesolr) and placed it in my Drupal modules folder (sites/all/modules/)
- Enabled `Apache Solr search` and `Apache Solr framework` modules in admin/modules
- Downloaded Apache Solr 4.2 from http://www.dsgnwrld.com/am/lucene/solr/4.6.0/
- Unpack it outside my drupal installation and outside my web root/folder. (~/srv/www/solr)
- Went to sites/all/modules/apachesolr/solr-conf/solr-4.x and copied all files to ~/srv/www/solr/example/solr/conf

I am stuck after this. I know I have to access my server at this address `~/srv/www/solr/example` through command prompt (Terminal) to start the Apache Service but how can I do that?

Plus, on the site, it's written that I can access the Solr admin interface by visiting
`http://localhost:8983/solr/admin`, but how can I do that when my site is located on a remote server?

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have solr 4.6 (rather than 4.2) from the link you presented but the steps are the same for both.

Although Solr can run in any Java Servlet Container of your choice, the example index includes a small installation of Jetty.

To launch Jetty with the Solr WAR, and the example configs, just run the start.jar ...

```
user:~$ cd ~/srv/www/solr/example
user:~/srv/www/solr/example$ java -jar start.jar
```

At that point the server should be listening on 0.0.0.0:8983.
You can then access this server using `http://remote.ip.or.hostname:8983/solr/admin`  (ex. `http://8.8.8.8:8983/solr/admin`)

You may want to consult the [tutorial](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_6_0/tutorial.html) in the docs for further information.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply ssnobody. One problem I am facing when entering `java -jar start.jar` is that it gives me ` command-not-found java`. It gives the same for yum, when I try to install java through `yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk` by showing `command-not-found yum`. Any help how I can install Java on my server as I guess it's needed for Solr. Many Thanks.

Comment: Is this a redhat based linux distribution? You may instead be using dpkg/apt, pacman, or something else for package management. If you are indeed using a redhat based distro and you don't have yum available, I would suggest you find a binary rpm package (rpmfind.net would likely be helpful here) of OpenJDK and install it (as well as it's dependencies) using rpm directly. (rpm -i)

Comment: I wanted to point out that it is generally much much easier to get java installed using package management than trying to piecemeal it yourself through rpms/debs, so you likely should look into why yum isn't working first and see if you can remedy that before embarking on the manual install method.

Comment: I completely agree with you sir. Thank you very much for your time.